# Shrub with white flowers

Tags: identification, shrubs

I saw this shrub (or small tree) yesterday with white flowers. Does anyone know what it is? It was found near the coast (dune area) in the Netherlands.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks rather like Prunus padus, but its difficult to be sure - not enough leaves in the image, only a close up view of both flowers and leaves (which is useful but one from further away would also be helpful) and no clue as to growth habit from the image you've posted.  http://wildflowerfinder.org.uk/Flowers/C/Cherry%28Bird%29/Cherry%28Bird%29.htm

Comment: That certainly looks like *Prunus padus*, the shrub is found in forests in the dune area (west of Netherlands). I will try to get back in late summer to see if the berries match.